# Is it better to download byte per byte in Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm building a File Sharing Program, and I would like to know if it's better, while using Sockets, to receive and send byte per byte, or a fixed amount. I'm sending messages of Login, Actual file size list, etc, of 512 bytes, and 65536, when sending and receiving files.

Comment: "Sorry if my english is bad, it's my native language." Err... did you mean that it's *not* your native language?

Comment: vote up and down and choose best between them if any of them was useful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is depend on your usage and goal:

**for High Performance when in non-faulty environment:**

choose 1500 bytes

**for bad and faulty environment:**

choose lower sizes but not byte per byte

Comment: Thank you all for the help. But all the messages should be 1500 or only when sending files?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use reasonably sized blocks for efficiency reasons. Typical network packets are around 1500 bytes in size (Ethernet) and every packet carries a bunch of necessary overhead (such as protocol, destination address and port etc.).

Single bytes is the worst (in terms of efficiency) that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Handling 1500 or so bytes at a time will be much more efficient than one byte at a time.  That is about the size of a typical Ethernet frame.

Keep in mind that you are using a stream of bytes: any concept of message or record is up to you to implement.